# Validator depends on Submit button and on attribute value

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem with a submit form.
I have personal constraint that depends on value of an attribute of my entity (attribute is not in my form).
The value must be set when I click on a specific submit button (I have multiple submit buttons).

My problem is that my validator is not applied.

Example :

Entity :

```
/**
* @MyPersonnalConstraint()
*/    
class Test
{
   private $id;
   private $text;
   private $text2;
   private $state;
}
```

FormType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
      ->add('text',    TextType::class)
      ->add('text2',   TextType::class)
      ->add('Submit1', SubmitType::class)
      ->add('Submit2', SubmitType::class);
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Test::class,
    ]);
}
```

MyPersonnalConstraintValidator

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if ($value->getState("X")) {   //<-- "X" is set only if "Submit2" is clicked
        if($value->getText2() === null || $value->getText2() === ""){
              $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                   ->atPath('text2')
                   ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on Submit2 Button I must do `$test->setState("X")`.

I can't use a `addEventListener(PRE_SUBMIT)` because my form is not submitted and boolean 'clicked' value is always false if clicking on 'Submit2'.

And

In my controller, after `handleRequest($request)` method I can catch `isClicked` on my button but it's too late for modify form data submitted `(setState("X"))` and `$form->isValid()` is always true.

Controller :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->get('Submit2')->isClicked()) {
    $form->getData()->setState("X");
}

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
     //Already valid
}
```

Thank's for your lights !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by taking it differently :

Entity

```
/**
* @MyPersonnalConstraint(groups={'mygroup'})    <--- Add Validation group
*/    
class Test
{
   private $id;
   private $text;
   private $text2;
   private $state;
}
```

FormType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
      ->add('text',    TextType::class)
      ->add('text2',   TextType::class)
      ->add('Submit1', SubmitType::class, array(
        'validation_groups' => array('mygroup', 'Default')  //<- Add Validation Group 
      ))
      ->add('Submit2', SubmitType::class);
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Test::class,
    ]);
}
```

MyPersonnalConstraintValidator

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
//Without test on getState        
if($value->getText2() === null || $value->getText2() === ""){
          $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
               ->atPath('text2')
               ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
   if ($form->get('Submit2')->isClicked()) {
        $test->setState("X");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to separate template logic (button clicks) and application one. You should add `state` hidden field to the form and listen to button clicks by javascript subscriber to set `state` field value depending on which button is pressed.